solana program gives: Reached maximum depth for account resolution error
Specs:
Macbook M1 pro(apple chip 16GB)
➜  anchor git:(main) ✗ anchor --version 
anchor-cli 0.30.1
➜  anchor git:(main) ✗ solana --version
solana-cli 2.0.17 (src:93e6e33e; feat:607245837, client:Agave)
➜  anchor git:(main) ✗ rustc --version
rustc 1.85.0-nightly (c94848c04 2024-12-05)

#![allow(clippy::result_large_err)]

use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("coUnmi3oBUtwtd9fjeAvSsJssXh5A5xyPbhpewyzRVF");

#[program]
pub mod solanadev {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize_poll(ctx: Context<InitializePoll>,
                           poll_id: u64,
                           description: String,
                           poll_start: u64,
                           poll_end: u64
                          ) -> Result<()>
    {
      let poll = &mut ctx.accounts.poll;

      poll.poll_id=  poll_id;
      poll.description = description;
      poll.poll_start = poll_start;
      poll.poll_end = poll_end;
      poll.candidate_amount = 0;
      Ok(())
    }

    pub fn initialize_candidate(ctx: Context<InitializeCandidate>,
                                candidate_name: String,
                                _poll_id: u64
                              ) -> Result<()>
    {
      let candidate = &mut ctx.accounts.candidate;
      let poll = &mut ctx.accounts.poll;
      poll.candidate_amount += 1;
      candidate.candidate_name = candidate_name;
      candidate.candidate_votes = 0;

      Ok(())

    }

    pub fn vote(ctx: Context<Vote>, _candidate_name: String, _pool_id: u64) -> Result<()> {
      let candidate = &mut ctx.accounts.candidate;
      msg!("candidate current: {}", candidate.candidate_name);

      candidate.candidate_votes += 1;
      msg!("Candidate name: {}", candidate.candidate_name);
      msg!("Candidate votes: {}", candidate.candidate_votes);
      Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(candidate_name: String, poll_id: u64)]
pub struct Vote<'info> {
  #[account(mut)]
  pub signer: Signer<'info>,

  #[account(
    mut,
    seeds = [poll_id.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
    bump
  )]
  pub poll: Account<'info, Poll>,

  #[account(
    mut,
    seeds = [candidate_name.as_bytes(), poll_id.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
    bump
  )]
  pub candidate: Account<'info, Candidate>
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(poll_id: u64)]
pub struct InitializePoll<'info> {

  #[account(mut)]
  pub signer: Signer<'info>,

  #[account(
    init,
    payer = signer,
    space = 8 + Poll::INIT_SPACE,
    seeds = [poll_id.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
    bump,
  )]
  pub poll: Account<'info, Poll>,

  pub system_program: Program<'info, System>

}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(candidate_name: String, poll_id: u64)]
pub struct InitializeCandidate<'info> {
  #[account(mut)]
  pub signer: Signer<'info>,

  #[account(
    mut,
    seeds = [poll_id.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
    bump
  )]
  pub poll: Account<'info, Poll>,

  #[account(
    init,
    payer = signer,
    space = 8 + Candidate::INIT_SPACE,
    seeds = [candidate_name.as_bytes(), poll_id.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
    bump
  )]
  pub candidate: Account<'info, Candidate>,

  pub system_program: Program<'info, System>

}

#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)]
pub struct Poll {
  pub poll_id: u64,
  #[max_len(280)]
  pub description: String,

  pub poll_start: u64,
  pub poll_end: u64,

  pub candidate_amount: u64
}

#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)]
pub struct Candidate {
  #[max_len(100)]
  pub candidate_name: String,
  pub candidate_votes: u64
}

This is the test file that I'm using to test the program.
First 3 test cases pass but the 3rd case that i use to vote fails
import * as anchor from '@coral-xyz/anchor'
import { Program } from '@coral-xyz/anchor'
import { Keypair, PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js'
import { Solanadev as Voting } from '../target/types/solanadev'
import { startAnchor } from 'solana-bankrun';
import { BankrunProvider } from 'anchor-bankrun';

const VOTE_IDL = require('../target/idl/solanadev.json');
const votingAddress = new PublicKey("coUnmi3oBUtwtd9fjeAvSsJssXh5A5xyPbhpewyzRVF")
describe('Voting', () => {
  let context, provider, votingProgram: any;
  beforeAll(async () => {
    context = await startAnchor("", [{ name: "solanadev", programId: votingAddress }], []);
    provider = new BankrunProvider(context);

    votingProgram = new Program<Voting>(
      VOTE_IDL,
      provider
    );
  })
  it('Initialize Poll', async () => {
    await votingProgram.methods.initializePoll(
      new anchor.BN(1),
      "Poll to choose b/w Trump and K",
      new anchor.BN(1733576212),
      new anchor.BN(1833596212)
    ).rpc();

    const [pollAddress] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [new anchor.BN(1).toArrayLike(Buffer, 'le', 8)],
      votingAddress
    );

    const poll = await votingProgram.account.poll.fetch(pollAddress);

    console.log(poll, "Poll details");

    expect(Number(poll.pollId)).toEqual(1);
    expect(poll.description).toEqual("Poll to choose b/w Trump and K");
    expect(Number(poll.pollStart)).toBeLessThan(Number(poll.pollEnd));
  })

  it("First Candidate", async () => {
    await votingProgram.methods.initializeCandidate("D", new anchor.BN(1)).rpc(); // New candidate initialized

    // Find the candidate address
    const [candidateAddress] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from("D"), new anchor.BN(1).toArrayLike(Buffer, 'le', 8)],
      votingAddress
    );

    const candidate = await votingProgram.account.candidate.fetch(candidateAddress);
    
    console.log(candidate, 'Candidate');
    

    expect(candidate.candidateName.toString()).toEqual("D");
    expect(candidate.candidateVotes.toNumber()).toEqual(0);
  })

  it("Second Candidate", async () => {
    await votingProgram.methods.initializeCandidate("K", new anchor.BN(1)).rpc(); // New candidate initialized

    // Find the candidate address
    const [candidateAddress] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from("K"), new anchor.BN(1).toArrayLike(Buffer, 'le', 8)],
      votingAddress
    );

    const candidate = await votingProgram.account.candidate.fetch(candidateAddress);
    
    console.log(candidate, 'Candidate');
    

    expect(candidate.candidateName.toString()).toEqual("K");
    expect(candidate.candidateVotes.toNumber()).toEqual(0);
  })

  it("Vote-1", async() => {
    const candidateName = "K";
    const pollId = new anchor.BN(1);
    console.log('$$$$$$$');
    
    // Invoke the voteCandidate instruction
    await votingProgram.methods
      .vote(candidateName, pollId)
      .rpc();

    console.log('$$$$$#######');
  
    // Find the candidate address
    const [candidateAddress] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from(candidateName), pollId.toArrayLike(Buffer, 'le', 8)],
      votingAddress // This should be your program ID
    );

    console.log('@@@@@@@@', candidateAddress);
  
    // Fetch the candidate account
    const candidate = await votingProgram.account.candidate.fetch(candidateAddress);
  
    console.log("Candidate votes", candidate.candidateVotes.toNumber());
  
    // Assert the vote count
    expect(candidate.candidateVotes.toNumber()).toEqual(1);
  })
})



Got the fix. Some changes that I did:
1 - Kept the poll_id as first parameter in the instruction in candidate and vote stuct and also used poll_id as first seed followed by candidate_name
2 - Changed the candidate.as_bytes() -> candidate.as_ref()
Here's the updated Code
#![allow(clippy::result_large_err)]

use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("coUnmi3oBUtwtd9fjeAvSsJssXh5A5xyPbhpewyzRVF");

#[program]
pub mod solanadev {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize_poll(ctx: Context<InitializePoll>,
                           poll_id: u64,
                           description: String,
                           poll_start: u64,
                           poll_end: u64
                          ) -> Result<()>
    {
      let poll = &mut ctx.accounts.poll;

      poll.poll_id=  poll_id;
      poll.description = description;
      poll.poll_start = poll_start;
      poll.poll_end = poll_end;
      poll.candidate_amount = 0;
      Ok(())
    }

    pub fn initialize_candidate(ctx: Context<InitializeCandidate>,
                                _poll_id: u64,
                                candidate_name: String
                              ) -> Result<()>
    {
      let candidate = &mut ctx.accounts.candidate;
      let poll = &mut ctx.accounts.poll;
      poll.candidate_amount += 1;
      candidate.candidate_name = candidate_name;
      candidate.candidate_votes = 0;

      Ok(())

    }

    pub fn vote(ctx: Context<Vote>, _poll_id: u64, _candidate_name: String) -> Result<()> {
      let candidate = &mut ctx.accounts.candidate;
      msg!("candidate current: {}", candidate.candidate_name);

      candidate.candidate_votes += 1;
      msg!("Candidate name: {}", candidate.candidate_name);
      msg!("Candidate votes: {}", candidate.candidate_votes);
      Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(poll_id: u64, candidate_name: String)]
pub struct Vote<'info> {
  #[account(mut)]
  pub signer: Signer<'info>,

  #[account(
    mut,
    seeds = [poll_id.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
    bump
  )]
  pub poll: Account<'info, Poll>,

  #[account(
    mut,
    seeds = [poll_id.to_le_bytes().as_ref(), candidate_name.as_ref()],
    bump
  )]
  pub candidate: Account<'info, Candidate>
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(poll_id: u64)]
pub struct InitializePoll<'info> {

  #[account(mut)]
  pub signer: Signer<'info>,

  #[account(
    init,
    payer = signer,
    space = 8 + Poll::INIT_SPACE,
    seeds = [poll_id.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
    bump,
  )]
  pub poll: Account<'info, Poll>,

  pub system_program: Program<'info, System>

}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(poll_id: u64, candidate_name: String)]
pub struct InitializeCandidate<'info> {
  #[account(mut)]
  pub signer: Signer<'info>,

  #[account(
    mut,
    seeds = [poll_id.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
    bump
  )]
  pub poll: Account<'info, Poll>,

  #[account(
    init,
    payer = signer,
    space = 8 + Candidate::INIT_SPACE,
    seeds = [poll_id.to_le_bytes().as_ref(), candidate_name.as_ref()],
    bump
  )]
  pub candidate: Account<'info, Candidate>,

  pub system_program: Program<'info, System>

}

#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)]
pub struct Poll {
  pub poll_id: u64,
  #[max_len(280)]
  pub description: String,

  pub poll_start: u64,
  pub poll_end: u64,

  pub candidate_amount: u64
}

#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)]
pub struct Candidate {
  #[max_len(100)]
  pub candidate_name: String,
  pub candidate_votes: u64
}

and the test cases
import * as anchor from '@coral-xyz/anchor'
import { Program } from '@coral-xyz/anchor'
import { Keypair, PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js'
import { Solanadev as Voting } from '../target/types/solanadev'
import { startAnchor } from 'solana-bankrun';
import { BankrunProvider } from 'anchor-bankrun';

const VOTE_IDL = require('../target/idl/solanadev.json');
const votingAddress = new PublicKey("coUnmi3oBUtwtd9fjeAvSsJssXh5A5xyPbhpewyzRVF")
describe('Voting', () => {
  let context, provider, votingProgram: any;
  beforeAll(async () => {
    context = await startAnchor("", [{ name: "solanadev", programId: votingAddress }], []);
    provider = new BankrunProvider(context);

    votingProgram = new Program<Voting>(
      VOTE_IDL,
      provider
    );
  })
  it('Initialize Poll', async () => {
    await votingProgram.methods.initializePoll(
      new anchor.BN(1),
      "Poll to choose b/w Trump and K",
      new anchor.BN(1733576212),
      new anchor.BN(1833596212)
    ).rpc();

    const [pollAddress] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [new anchor.BN(1).toArrayLike(Buffer, 'le', 8)],
      votingAddress
    );

    const poll = await votingProgram.account.poll.fetch(pollAddress);

    console.log(poll, "Poll details");

    expect(Number(poll.pollId)).toEqual(1);
    expect(poll.description).toEqual("Poll to choose b/w Trump and K");
    expect(Number(poll.pollStart)).toBeLessThan(Number(poll.pollEnd));
  })

  it("First Candidate", async () => {
    await votingProgram.methods.initializeCandidate(new anchor.BN(1), "Donald").rpc(); // New candidate initialized

    // Find the candidate address
    const [candidateAddress] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [new anchor.BN(1).toArrayLike(Buffer, 'le', 8), Buffer.from("Donald")],
      votingAddress
    );

    const candidate = await votingProgram.account.candidate.fetch(candidateAddress);
    
    console.log(candidate, 'Candidate');
    

    expect(candidate.candidateName.toString()).toEqual("Donald");
    expect(candidate.candidateVotes.toNumber()).toEqual(0);
  })

  it("Second Candidate", async () => {
    await votingProgram.methods.initializeCandidate(new anchor.BN(1), "Kamala").rpc(); // New candidate initialized

    // Find the candidate address
    const [candidateAddress] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [new anchor.BN(1).toArrayLike(Buffer, 'le', 8), Buffer.from("Kamala")],
      votingAddress
    );

    const candidate = await votingProgram.account.candidate.fetch(candidateAddress);
    
    console.log(candidate, 'Candidate');
    

    expect(candidate.candidateName.toString()).toEqual("Kamala");
    expect(candidate.candidateVotes.toNumber()).toEqual(0);
  })

  it("Vote-1", async() => {
    const candidateName = "Kamala";
    const pollId = new anchor.BN(1);
    console.log('$$$$$$$');
    
    // Invoke the voteCandidate instruction
    await votingProgram.methods
      .vote(pollId, candidateName)
      .rpc();

    console.log('$$$$$#######');
  
    // Find the candidate address
    const [candidateAddress] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [pollId.toArrayLike(Buffer, 'le', 8), Buffer.from(candidateName)],
      votingAddress // This should be your program ID
    );

    console.log('@@@@@@@@', candidateAddress);
  
    // Fetch the candidate account
    const candidate = await votingProgram.account.candidate.fetch(candidateAddress);
  
    console.log("Candidate votes", candidate.candidateVotes.toNumber());
  
    // Assert the vote count
    expect(candidate.candidateVotes.toNumber()).toEqual(1);
  })
})


